# Mclust and factorial data: R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, factor-analysis

I'm trying to do some clustering with R and I need some help:
The first step was a factorial analysis of percentage data and the results are 4 factors.

After that I would like to try some mixture model with MClust and from here there some problems.

```
Clustering <- Mclust(Data$ClinicalT0,Data&ClinicalT1, Data$%Data, G = 4, modelNames = c("VII"))
```

The error is:

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

So I tried to write it differently as   `....Data["ClinicalT0]...`

but then again:

```
 sort(as.integer(unique(G))): 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
```

They are not "atomic" but they are dataframe, and Mclust is supposed to work with dataframes.

How should I write this code? I think It's a problem to include the "factors" resulting from the factorial analysis, but I can't find how to use them properly.

Some examples from str(Data):
[image]

Comment: We can't tell as long as we don't know what your objects are. What is ```Data```? Can you give the output of ```str(Data)``` (in the question)?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Data is a dataframe of 87 columns all numerical except the first one which is the ID.

The values are all whole numbers. Some columns are dicotomic, but not the ones I considered for this analysis

Comment: You only show a part so we still don't know what ```Data$ClinicalT0``` or ```Data$%Data``` are, but anyway, ```MClust``` seems to expect a data frame, but your data frame seems to be ```Data```, not ```Data$ClinicalT0```. Also you seem to have three inputs before ```G```, but ```Mclust``` only wants a single one. Read its help page.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect for me to show to you.
"Data" is a Gene and it is the name of this dataset.
I have firstly the results about the expression of this gene in percentage(%Data) and then I have clinical variables (dataclinical) of the subjects for which I study the gene expression. 

I suppose that Mclust takes only one argument, but How can I consder all three of these data for a clustering?

Comment: You probably need to do `Data[, "column"]` not `Data["column"]` nor `Data$column`

Comment: There's multiple syntax errors in your question `Data$%Data` isn't a valid column specification. Neither is `Data&ClinicalT1`. Nor `Data["ClinicalT0]`